# How do you get Task Scheduler to run a task as SYSTEM? I use Windows 10, but am uncertain how to do this

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

How do you get Task Scheduler to run a task as SYSTEM?

I use Windows 10, but am uncertain how to do this.

Comment: Just run the Task as an admin user. System is reserved for system tasks, not user tasks.

Comment: @John not the best advise. I've used the SYSTEM user for tasks myself. Its perfectly capable and allowed and even handy in some situations.

Comment: Good point. I still tend to use my own user for the one or two tasks I need. Other tasks (part of the Lenovo and Windows system that came with the machine) are almost always SYSTEM tasks.

Comment: at least in the enterprise, never use your own account for a scheduled task. use a local account or a "service" account that multiple parties can use. you wouldn't want all your tasks to stop running just because you got a new job and your account was disabled, and using your own account prevents other administrators from editing the tasks you create.

Answer (score 3):

When you schedule your task, There is a field where you can choose which user to use. Click Change, and a new window pops up. Type SYSTEM and press check names, then select the user when it finds it.

This should change the username to `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM`

Your task will now run as SYSTEM user.

Do note, SYSTEM user has full access on your local machine only. If the task relies on a network share, it will fail.

Keep in mind, that you cannot change anymore whether or not the user is logged in. The reason is, that it now always runs whether or not the user is logged in.

The benefit of doing this, is that you can make a task run as admin without worrying that a password change stops the task from running, but only for tasks that do not do anything outside the local machine. SYSTEM cannot access the network nor the internet.

Note, Windows 10 Pro or higher might be required to do this, but I'm not 100% sure.